# Random URL's in access.log

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, proxy

My server recently started getting a massive increase in the number of random URL requests.

- `124.173.67.77 - - [23/Jul/2016:21:21:04 -0400] "GET http://www.059boss.com/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 12040 "http://www.059boss.com/index.php" "http://www.059boss.com/index.php"`
- `195.182.131.107 - - [23/Jul/2016:21:21:04 -0400] "GET http://ascon-profi.ru/common/proxy.php HTTP/1.1" 404 474 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208"`
- `155.94.224.168 - - [23/Jul/2016:21:21:04 -0400] "GET http://www.daqimeng.com/user/login HTTP/1.1" 404 470 "http://www.baidu.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; http://www.google.com/bot.html)"`
- `119.29.32.85 - - [23/Jul/2016:21:21:04 -0400] "GET http://www.tianx.top/ HTTP/1.0" 200 11992 "http://www.so.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; zh-CN; rv:1.8.0.11) Gecko/20070312 Firefox/1.5.0.11; 360Spider"`

These all look like proxy requests, but some are (some of them) returning 200 responses, which is definitely NOT a good thing.  I'm reasonably sure that mod_proxy isn't enabled anywhere, but it's possible it is.  How do I rectify this?

Comment: a large ISP in china has a flaky DNS server, start serving content that the Chinese govt doesn't like if you get a request for a domain you don't host.

Comment: when it was hitting my servers it was mostly torrent requests, you seem to be getting traffic intended for a proxy server.

Comment: You should certainly verify your virtual host configuration as none of those requests should have gotten a 200.

Comment: It could do that if the person sets up a custom host / DNS entry pointing to your IP and your Apache directs all requests to your domain's virtual host.